# Eclipse helios install new plugin problem

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install new plugin but when I choose the update site I got this error

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0
>   2010-10-07 08:57:56.153 !MESSAGE
>   Provisioning exception !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException:
>   Bad HTTP Request:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6/compositeContent.xml
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:189)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:747)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:100)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:249)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     ... 1 more !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 4
>   1002 2010-10-07 08:57:56.153 !MESSAGE
>   Bad HTTP Request:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6/compositeContent.xml
>   !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:249)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ecf.identity 4
>   0 2010-10-07 08:57:56.153 !MESSAGE
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0
>   2010-10-07 08:57:56.384 !MESSAGE
>   Provisioning exception !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException:
>   Bad HTTP Request:
>   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6/content.xml
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:189)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:747)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:100)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:249)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     ... 1 more !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 4
>   1002 2010-10-07 08:57:56.385 !MESSAGE
>   Bad HTTP Request:
>   http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6/content.xml
>   !STACK 1
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:249)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ecf.identity 4
>   0 2010-10-07 08:57:56.385 !MESSAGE
>   HttpClient connection error response
>   code 400.

I have tried this with many update sites and I got the same error, so what is this?if someone interested in the full log I can post it.

Thanks

Comment: Please open the error log (Windows → Show View → Error Log or locate it in the Workspace under .metadata/.log). Locate the full exception, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem, What I did was I had previously set a proxy address so when I went to a network that required no proxy, I got that error.

I solved the problem by

1. Preferences
2. Network connection
3. Then set network provider to Direct.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and by following various options mentioned above I could able to find a solution for ProvisionException:

Solution:
If you are behind proxy, set the network option to "manual" and provide the proxy host, port. If the proxy needs authentication provide the username and password.

I am assuming if you are not behind proxy you can use "Direct" option in network setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your URLs, it seems you just entered wrong ones. Try the following:

1. Open the Help → Install new software.
2. Use the Helios main site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
3. Make sure to turn off "contact all update sites..."
4. Try to install something and see if it works.

It seems you are just using the wrong URLs and you have some bad update sites. To remove the update sites that don't work, go to the Preferences → Install/Update → Available Software Sites. In this list, locate the bad site and remove them.

Also, I would suggest turning off the "contact all update sites..." as a common practice, unless the installation fails and you really need to install a dependency from another site.

You can find more tips on plugins installation in [my blog post](http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/07/ten-tips-for-installing-plugins-in-eclipse-galileo.html).

Comment: thanks I can't install anything from anywhere for example I tried helios main update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios but I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, What I did was I had downloaded the below checkstyle plugin files and added in the STC plugin folder and its working fine.

```
net.sf.eclipsecs.branding_5.9.0.201410282234.jar
net.sf.eclipsecs.checkstyle_5.9.0.201410282234.jar
net.sf.eclipsecs.core_5.9.0.201410282234.jar
net.sf.eclipsecs.doc_5.9.0.201410282234.jar
net.sf.eclipsecs.ui_5.9.0.201410282234.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste eclipse in program files and run it from there. Due to some permission problem it may not run. If you run it from downloads folder or from Desktop